# Can I host my own bare git repo on my remote server?

Tags: git, github, webserver

Im all aware about services like github and such which provide a really nice system for everything. But what I want to know is, can I use my own webserver?

The server is not owned by me, im in a shared host. So this is not my own box I can make modifications to.

I dont need a fancy front end, I dont need any extra mumbo-jumbo, quite simply I just want to be able to clone and push to a bare git repo on this webserver.

What ive tried so far, is initializing a bare repo on my local drives, cloning it somewhere else, and comitting a blank readme, then pushing that to the "remote" repo. 
I think made a 755 directory on my server called "git" and then uploaded the bare git repo (in this case its a folder called test.git) to this directory. so the directory is 
/git/test.git

However when I attempt to even just clone this, i get

> Cloning into test... error: The requested URL returned error: 500
>   while accessing http://blackjaguarstudios.com/git/test.git/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

So there's obviously something im not doing, question is, is it even possible?

I don't *care* about security really, im just looking for a tad more privacy than paying for github private repos for slightly more sensitive stuff, but nothing earth shattering if someone found them :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.  Serving that via HTTP is relatively complex, and you didn't mention anything about how you configured your web server to serve the `/git` path, so can't specifically advise on that.  You probably want to do something akin to http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html if you do want to serve by HTTP though.

On the other hand, the *easy* way to do this is to use a SSH remote:

```
git remote add me-at-example user@example.com:/git/test.git
```

That will give you full read/write access over the SSH connection, and allow you to push and pull to that remote safely.  No server, and no credentials needed beyond what you already use to log in via SSH.

The one thing to remember is that git changes files with the ownership of whoever you SSH in as - so, if you want more than one person modifying that repository, have them connect as one user, or make sure their groups and umasks are right.

Comment: This is how we use Git at our office, and it was a breeze to set up (mostly).

Comment: As i mentioned in my original post, I have no access to make modifications to the server, im on a shared host. Therefore I cannot implement what progits telling me to do. I also have no ssh connectivity to my server, I was really hoping the HTTP protocol would just kind of work haha it was a high hope, but its all good! I know for the future and thats exactly what I asked for! I ended up going with Adams answer ultimately for Bitbucket and their unlimited multi-user private repos. This makes my life easier. Github for public, BB for private ;) win-win!

Comment: @DJDarkViper - I thought your host might be able to run a CGI script, but if not, not.  http://progit.org/book/ch4-5.html is about setting up read-only git HTTP access, but without something running on the server that can write files, you can't have read/write HTTP access.

Comment: thats absolutely fair enough haha would want write privvys!

Answer (score 1):

bitbucket gives you private git repos for free. Also checkout unfuddle.com.

I would not go with a host that is not used to hosting git repositories.

Webservers will not be dependable for keeping certain non-web ports open.

Comment: reason for downvote please! Web servers don't make great remote repos when the hosting company decides to block ports that are not used for web requests. Own up to the downvote :|

Comment: I did not originally vote this down, but added one because the contains a non-answer, and an unspecified "you shouldn't do this, but I won't tell you why".  If you expanded to explain *why* it is a bad idea, ideally with supporting evidence, I wouldn't have voted down.

Comment: Much better.  Even if I don't agree with you, you justify why you think that. :)

Comment: The answer to the question is definitely what Daniel had provided, problem being as ive mentioned in my post is I have no access to the server so i cant set anything up, especially protocols. So I ended up going with Bitbucket. See last time I was at BB, it was only doing Mercurial which I do not use, and therefore didnt think I had any business with. I really wanted to mark your answer as correct, but its merely a workaround to a deficiency that I cannot control, but if I did would have been able to implement Daniels answer correctly.I appreciate the direction though, this is what I needed +1